# Does な have a purpose in あの人のことが嫌い**な**わけではないが、一緒にいるとちょっと疲れる。 or is it just a mistake?

Tags: particle-な

Does な have a purpose in  あの人のことが嫌い**な**わけではないが、一緒にいるとちょっと疲れる。 or is it just a mistake?

Comment: 嫌い is a な type adjective.

Comment: @A.Ellett you're right, i thought it's i-adj.